# Why does XML::Simple flatten this Tomboy note?

Tags: xml, perl

I'm trying to parse a [Tomboy](http://projects.gnome.org/tomboy/) note that has a link to another note inside it.  The XML comes out looking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<note version="0.3" xmlns:link="http://beatniksoftware.com/tomboy/link" xmlns:size="http://beatniksoftware.com/tomboy/size" xmlns="http://beatniksoftware.com/tomboy">
  <title>Our IP Blocks</title>
  <text xml:space="preserve"><note-content version="0.1">Our IP Blocks

What's <link:internal>in use</link:internal>?</note-content></text>
  <last-change-date>2009-03-10T10:24:36.3730770-04:00</last-change-date>
  <last-metadata-change-date>2009-03-10T10:24:36.3730770-04:00</last-metadata-change-date>
  <create-date>2009-03-10T10:23:14.2936280-04:00</create-date>
  <cursor-position>92</cursor-position>
  <width>450</width>
  <height>289</height>
  <x>0</x>
  <y>27</y>
  <open-on-startup>False</open-on-startup>
</note>
```

I'm parsing this with [XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~grantm/XML-Simple-2.18/lib/XML/Simple.pm), and it's pulling out the `<link:internal />` node in to a separate object within perl.

**EDIT:**  The resulting object (for the `<text />` node looks like this.  Note that 'link:internal' is a separate entity from 'content'.

```
'text' => {
  'xml:space' => 'preserve',
  'note-content' => {
    'version' => '0.1',
    'link:internal' => 'in use',
    'content' => [
        'Our IP Blocks
        What\'s ',
        '?'
    ]
  }
}
```

Is this a bug, or am I crazy?  All of the validators suggest that this is valid XML, but I've never seen it with a tag nested inside text like this before.

If it is a bug, does anyone know of another XML module that will get this right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

XML::Simple is not a proper parsing module for general XML parsing. It was designed with one purpose in mind, that is: parsing config files in XML format. So it simplifies the data somewhat — or a lot, depending on what you feed it. If you care about order of text and tags, you shouldn't be using this module.

Comment: This is the right answer.  You're expecting your parse tree to be ordered, like it is in the markup, but XML::Simple is flattening it into an object with 'fields' like "link:internal".  Look at XML::Parser::Style::Tree for the representation you probably want.

Answer (score 2):

The above is entirely valid XML. You have an opening element followed by a text node followed by an opening element.

I'm guessing (perhaps) that the text you're parsing hasn't been properly escaped before inserting into the top-level node. e.g. perhaps it *should* be

```
What's &lt;link:internal&gt;in use&lt;/link:internal&gt;
```

That would then result in getting the text as one text node and the contents not being parsed (if I'm reading this correctly).

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not my option to do this.  I'm only taking what I get from Tomboy's file structure.

Comment: I think you'll have to take the contents of your top level node and reparse as text, then (regenerating and escaping as appropriate).